# Leaded Ferrite bead good choice for winding my own coils?

Tags: ferrite-bead

I have never designed directly with a ferrite bead:

[image: pic here]

I want to wind my own inductor coils, and these seems useful for the fact that it has a ferrite core and some hefty leads coming out. I'd wrap my magnetic coil around the core and then solder the fine gauge mag wire to the leads. The final application would conveniently solder to the hefty leads.

My question is: Are the two leads part of the same conductor (a single wire fed through the ferrite core), or is there isolation between the two ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ferrite beads are typically designed to be lossy, to absorb energy that would otherwise be conducted or radiated as EMI.  Therefore if you want a high Q inductor they are a bad choice for a core.

Also, wrapping wire around the core the way you describe (if I understand correctly) would increase your inductance but soldering the ends to the wire through the bead would short out your coil. The core is not intended to be used in this way and you would be way better off getting some ferrite cores intended for the application you are looking at.

The two leads are a part of the same conductor, usually its just a conductor through the core or sometimes with 1 or 2 turns through a core.